# How do you install JOGL on windows 7 64bit for use with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

I've tried to follow any number of [tutorials](http://schabby.de/jogl-example-hello-world/):

But I still can't get eclipse to recognise any of my import statements:

```
import net.java.games.jogl.Animator;
import net.java.games.jogl.GL;
import net.java.games.jogl.GLCanvas;
import net.java.games.jogl.GLCapabilities;
import net.java.games.jogl.GLDrawable;
import net.java.games.jogl.GLDrawableFactory;
import net.java.games.jogl.GLEventListener;
```

Having said that there always seems to be something different with the tutorials and what I am able to do (ie different files, different packages, different steps etc).

[This tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/sites/system/errors/WebspaceNotFound?path=/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-1) installs JOGL as a user library which I like but references files ( nativewindow.all.jar, newt.all.jar) that I could not find in the JOGL download I found. It also talks about referencing .dll files which the download help.txt and wiki state are deprecated and should not be used. Having said that I followed the instructions as best I could (using files mentioned in wiki) but it still doesn't work.

[The official wiki](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL) talks about downloading different packages for different systems, but they all seemed to be bundled into one "jogamp-all-platforms.7z" file now. It says the files you need are: "gluegen-rt.jar, jogl.all.jar, gluegen-java-src.zip, jogl-java-src.zip, gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar, jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar" but it doesn't say what you are supposed to do with them. (I've referenced them in my build path, but it hasn't worked).

Anyway I am probably doing something very stupid, but am not sure what.

Can someone give step by step newbie-proof instructions on how to add JOGL to my eclipse project?

EDIT****
Here's an image of my project properties window:
 [image: my project properties window]

Comment: Have you tried unzipping the *.7z file?

Comment: I wouldn't put that past me, but yes I have!

Comment: Grabbing a recent build from here: http://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/master/ and referencing the 6 jars you mentioned (as per official wiki) worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The user library JOGL is fine. However you are duplicating it again under GameTutorials/lib. I think this tell jogl not to look any deeper. Try removing the jogl jar files under GameTutorials/lib, but keep the jogl jar files under the jogl user library. That should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right it was a mess, I had tried all the different ways on top of one another. I have now got rid of everything in the lib folder and removed all references from the build path apart from the jogl user library I created. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I also removed a path to a native library in one of the jars inside the jogl user library as native stuff is meant to be in the jars already apparently. Still no joy...

Comment: Now that I look at your code even closer, you are building jogl1 (which is not maintained anymore). You should use jogl2 from Jogamp.org. And when you do import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;